# Old product url to new product url redirect in magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.7, url, url-rewrite, product-urls

Well this might be duplicate of others but it didn't got my answer...

Okay so I want to redirect user from old product url to new product url so by googling I've found following code....

Here I'm passing following variables in `createRuleCommunity` function.

```
$fromUrl = 'http://www.example.com/product-old-url.html';
$toUrl   = 'http://www.example.com/product-new-url.html';

public function createRuleCommunity($fromUrl, $toUrl)
    {
        // Create rewrite:
        /** @var Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite $rewrite */
        $rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite');
        $this->storeIds = Mage::app()->getStores();
        // Check for existing rewrites:
        foreach($this->storeIds as $storeId)
        {
            // Attempt loading it first, to prevent duplicates:
            $rewrite->loadByIdPath($fromUrl);

            $rewrite->setStoreId($storeId);
            $rewrite->setOptions('RP');
            $rewrite->setIdPath($fromUrl);
            $rewrite->setRequestPath($fromUrl);
            $rewrite->setIsSystem(0);
            $rewrite->setTargetPath($toUrl);

            $rewrite->save();
        }
    }
```

After executing this function when I visit

```
http://www.example.com/product-old-url.html
```

It's not direceting me to new url which is `http://www.example.com/product-new-url.html`

And new url (`http://www.example.com/product-new-url.html`) is become `404 Error`

I want when user visit following url

```
http://www.example.com/product-old-url.html
```

He/She should be redirected to new url

```
http://www.example.com/product-new-url.html
```

So in short by any visiting old url user should be redirect to new product url.

So is there any direct way to do so??

All I've is product old url and new url and I want to do this job programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyways following has done the job..

```
    // get the new url
    $new_url = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_url')->formatUrlKey('new-product-url');

    // load the product object
    $_product =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$product['sku']);

    // save rewrites history for old to new url redirect
    $_product->setData('save_rewrites_history', true);

    // set new url
    $_product->setUrlKey($new_url);

    // set new url path
    $_product->setUrlPath($new_url);

    // save the product
    $_product->save();
```

After executing above script just reindex

> Catalog URL Rewrites index

After that try to visit your old url and you will be redirected to the new url.